# How to update or insert an iframe into database using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, iframe

I have a textarea in my front-end which accepts the google map code which is an iframe. When I tried to update it, the query fails. The values is not getting inserted into the database. I use text for saving iframe in db. The code I use in model :

```
function save(){            
     $data['cmpny_address'] = $this->input->post('cmpny_address');   
     $data['cmpny_map'] = $this->input->post('cmpny_map'); 
     $this->db->where('id',1);
     $this->db->update('contact_us', $data); 
}
```

I have tried sanitizing the input with htmlspecialchars, strip_tags, $this->db->escape etc. I have actually tried all the suggestions from related SO questions. But no luck. Somebody please suggest a way to fix the issue.

**EDIT**: 
It is the `<iframe></iframe>` that is creating the problem. `<p></p> , <h1></h1>` gets through without any error.

Comment: This is not the insert query . You are updating your data.

Comment: @Saty: Sorry, I will edit the question.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark your query as resolved. To do that here, the best approach is to add an answer, which you can self-accept by clicking the tick symbol. We prefer that the solution is _not_ added to the question - it does not belong there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

It was a server issue. The support team said "modsecurity was blocking it".

Answer (score 0):

No need to write any `htmlspecialchars`and `strip_tags` Active record automatically handle all those thing.

Use `set` method to update your data

```
function save(){            
     $this->db->set("cmpny_address", $this->input->post('cmpny_address'));
     $this->db->set("cmpny_map", $this->input->post('cmpny_map'));
     $this->db->where('id',1);
     $this->db->update('contact_us'); 
}
```

OR

create you data array like

```
$data=array('cmpny_address'=>$this->input->post('cmpny_address'),'cmpny_map'=>$this->input->post('cmpny_map'));
$this->db->where('id',1);
$this->db->update('contact_us', $data);
```

UPDATED

To send iframe into post you have to set

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

In your `config.php` file

Comment: Not working.. I think it is the problem of <iframe></iframe> and not the query...

Comment: What is the value of `$this->input->post('cmpny_address')` and `$this->input->post('cmpny_map')` ??

Comment: cmpny_address = "sometext"; and cmpny_map = <iframe></iframe>

Comment: just try with `html_entity_decode($this->input->post('cmpny_map'));`

Comment: Just now I noticed one thing. In my test server it updates without any problem but in live this error occurs. What might be the cause of this?

Comment: it means your iframe is not post

Comment: set `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;` in config.php file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84640/discussion-between-arshad-and-saty).